# php email attachement, works but the attachment is corrupt

Tags: php, email, attachment

i have created a form that can send and email with a specified attachment, it come through to my mail address ok, and seem to work fine untill i attempt to open the file, it tell me its damaged or corrupt, i think this is down to my headers.

here is my code.

http://pastebin.com/Y0MUHzSs

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would add a .txt file as an attachment, look into it and see what PHP adds to corrupt it.

Comment: Is the email corrupt? Or the attachment corrupt? Have you checked what in the file is corrupted? Also, have you tried not chunking the data before you encode it?

Comment: its the attachement i reckon, i have removed the chunk split and base64 and the text file is out putting the text perfect, but when i wrap those functions around it it out puts random characters, but if i attach an image or a zip file, the data is corrupt/damaged with either method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the PHP mail function with attachments is pure pain. Just use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) for that purpose. This library does everything you need to send the correct encoding and mimetype of the attachment.